# Unity CG "shadow catcher" shader not showing in iOS

Tags: ios, shader, unity-game-engine, shadow

I have this shader on two planes. It makes them transparent and only shows the shadow they receive. However, compiling and running it on iOS makes the shadows go away and I cant figure out why. Any ideas?

```
Shader "FX/Matte Shadow" {

Properties {

    _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)

    _MainTex ("Base (RGB) Trans (A)", 2D) = "white" {}

    _Cutoff ("Alpha cutoff", Range(0,1)) = 0.5

}


SubShader {

    Tags {"Queue"="AlphaTest" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="TransparentCutout"}

    LOD 200

    Blend Zero SrcColor


CGPROGRAM

    #pragma surface surf ShadowOnly alphatest:_Cutoff


fixed4 _Color;

struct Input {

    float2 uv_MainTex;

};


inline fixed4 LightingShadowOnly (SurfaceOutput s, fixed3 lightDir, fixed atten)

{

    fixed4 c;


    c.rgb = s.Albedo*atten;

    c.a = s.Alpha;

    return c;

}


void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {

    fixed4 c = _Color;

    o.Albedo = c.rgb;

    o.Alpha = 1;

}

ENDCG

}

Fallback "Transparent/Cutout/VertexLit"

}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be using alphatest shaders in IOS. They cause a lot of fill rate problems, which might also be the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shader works perfectly fine. My problem has been the far clipping plane wich wouldn't go all the way to the wall when testing the AR-App on a iOS device. Oops.